# Coordinate finding in 3D having relative distances

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm working on a web 3D Map tool for a famous space game (NMS), and I'm having some trouble finding coordinates for the planets inside its 3d space.

All the galaxies are located in a bounding box with limits *(0,0,0)* and *(409600,25600,409600)*, with the universe center at *(204700,12700,204700)*.

Each galaxy bounding box is a 100x100x100 cube, and their center coordinates are shown ingame in hundreds (like *(1,1,1)* for your current galaxy, which is *(100,100,100)* in euclidean space).

Planets inside a galaxy show distance to the center of the universe and between themselves, but no euclidean space coordinates (like 34,5 to next one and 165432,7 to the center)

I know how to check distance in XYZ between two points in 3D space and tested ok with galaxy coordinates & the center. But I'm lost in the planets part.

There is a way to find the planets XYZ coordinates (limited by the galaxy bounding box) knowing that distances to center and between them?

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can't get the XYZ coordinates. Assume for instance that all planets are far from the bounding box of the galaxy. If you rotate all the planets around the center of the universe by a small angle, so that they are still inside their bounding boxes, you conserve both the inter planet distance and the distance to the center of the universe.